# Prevent Table split in apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I am facing an issue while generating the docx file using apache poi library.
I have multiple tables of variable sizes to be included dynamically in the document.The issue is that table gets splited between the pages.My requirement is to prevent the table from splitting between the pages.In poi library i found the method `table.getRow(0).setCantSplitRow(true);` but does not changes anything.Any suggestions for how to implement this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: setCantSplitRow(true) not working for me either

Answer (score 1):

Try using Table Row Function :

```
**setCantSplitRow(boolean split)
```

This attribute controls whether to allow table rows to split across pages.**

tableRow.setCantSplitRow(true);

Comment: this work just for row

Answer (score 0):

To make table unsplittable you should set for all paragraphs in table property "isKeepNext = true" like this (for kotlin):

```
fun XWPFTable.setUnsplittable(): XWPFTable {
return apply {
    rows.map { row ->
        row.tableCells.map { cell ->
            cell.paragraphs.map { paragraph ->
                if (paragraph.ctp?.pPr == null) paragraph.ctp.addNewPPr().addNewKeepLines()
                paragraph.isKeepNext = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

So if you want to check how it works in MS Word, you can select table and include "keep with next" in paragraph settings, and finally save docuemnt in .xml and see that isKeepNext is used for all paragraphs =)

Comment: so I have not found property for table like setCantSplitRow for rows